# RunTime Error for linked list delete function

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I have a list of CDs that I append to a linked list. I can successfully append CDs and display them. But when I try to remove a CD by only using the the CD name as the argument I get a RunTime check error#3 The variable 'previousNode' is being used  without being intialized. So when I intialize it to 0 and call the remove function the program encounters an error and needs to close. It builds fine. How do I set deleteNode with the correct arguments? Or is something wrong with the deleteNode function? I need to ask the user which cd to delete and delete that cd. Please let me know if you need to see anymore code. This is what I append to the node. CD NAME, ARTIST, LENGTH, SONG, SONG TITLE, SONG LENGTH, but I only want the user to enter the CD NAME and the whole node will be deleted.

Remove function in Main

```
void remove_cd(LinkedList1<CD> *del)
{
    string name;        // To hold name of CD
    cout << "CD name to remove: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);
    CD cd(name);
    del->deleteNode(cd);
}
```

Linked list delete function

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList1 
{
private:
// Declare a structure
struct discList
{
    T value;
    struct discList *next;  // To point to the next node
};
discList *head;     // List head pointer
public:
// Default Constructor
LinkedList1()
{ head = NULL; }
// Destructor
~LinkedList1();
// Linked list operations
void appendNode(T);
void insertNode(T);
void deleteNode(T);
void displayList() const;
};

template<class T>
void LinkedList1<T>::deleteNode( T searchValue)
{
    discList *nodePtr;          // To traverse the list
    discList *previousNode;     // To point to the previous node

    // If the list is empty, do nothing
    if (!head)
        return;

    // Determine if the first node is the one
    if (head->value==searchValue)
    {
        nodePtr = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nodePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        // Intialize nodePtr to head of list
        nodePtr = head;

        while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value != searchValue)
        {
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        if (nodePtr)
        {
            previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
            delete nodePtr;
        }
    }
}
```

Overloaded operators defined in CD. Could these be the issue?

```
bool CD::operator != (const CD &e)
{
    if (name != e.name)
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool CD::operator == (const CD &e)
{
    if (name == e.name)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the "else" you should initialize as

```
    previousNode = head;
    nodePtr = head->next;
```

Also I just noticed the following:

```
void LinkedList1<T>::deleteNode( T searchValue)
{
    discList *nodePtr;          // To traverse the list
    discList *previousNode;
```

It looks very suspicious to me as `discList` should be somehow related to `T`. It should be something like

```
    Node<T> *nodePtr
```

Comment: I tried that. This way won't give me an error code but it also doesn't delete the node.

Comment: Are you sure that the type you are using your template class with properly implement the `==` **and** the `!=` operators ?

Comment: sorry discList is the name of the struct of the linkedlist

Comment: I get that. But how comes that it is not templated on `T` ? Please post its definition.

Comment: Ok ! My bad. Since it's a member of `LinkeduList1` it doesn't need the `T` parameter. At this point I've no more idea (and also time). You should 1) try to use a debugger to find what's happening and 2) If you don't manage to figure it out, post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) here.

Comment: Ok I am going to look at how I am appending the nodes to make sure all the info is appending to one node